# AWR report in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying the generate AWR report in oracle 11G. At the creation time, i am getting some error message. error is mentioned below

> Using the report name awrrpt_1_2504_2709.html. select output from
>   table(dbms_workload_repository.awr_report_html( :dbid,
>                            * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Steps that i am using for generate the AWR reports

> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql
>
> Enter value for report_type: html
>
> Enter value for begin_snap: 2504 Begin Snapshot Id specified: 2504
>
> Enter value for end_snap: 2709 End   Snapshot Id specified: 2709

Please help me on this.

Comment: Don't forget it's a licensed option on Enterprise Edition only as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user, you're using to generate AWR must not be having execute privileges on `DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY` package.

To quote from Oracle Documentation,

> ..To invoke these procedures, a user must be granted the DBA role.

Here is the list of `GRANTS` you would need to generate AWR

```
GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$DATABASE TO MY_USER;

GRANT SELECT ON SYS.V_$INSTANCE TO MY_USER;

GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY TO MY_USER;

GRANT SELECT ON SYS.DBA_HIST_DATABASE_INSTANCE TO MY_USER;

GRANT SELECT ON SYS.DBA_HIST_SNAPSHOT TO MY_USER;

GRANT ADVISOR TO MY_USER;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that Oracle 18c throws the same error and I was connected as sys and with the sysdba role.

Answer (score 0):

conn / as sysdba

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

Specify the Report Type

```
AWR reports can be generated in the following formats. Please enter the
name of the format at the prompt. Default value is 'html'.

'html' HTML format (default)
'text' Text format
'active-html' Includes Performance Hub active report

Enter value for report_type:
old 1: select 'Type Specified: ',lower(nvl('&&report_type','html')) report_type from dual
new 1: select 'Type Specified: ',lower(nvl('','html')) report_type from dual

Type Specified: html

old 1: select '&&report_type' report_type_def from dual
new 1: select 'html' report_type_def from dual



old 1: select '&&view_loc' view_loc_def from dual
new 1: select 'AWR_PDB' view_loc_def from dual
```